# how to redirect with query parameters from router file

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a router that accepts queryParams, it can include or not a queryParam for language for example: ?lang=de

when I navigate using router it works:

```
this.router.navigate(['/routeToNavigate'], { queryParams: queryParams })
```

My problem is in routing file:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  canActivate: [ValidUserGuard],
  runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: '/main',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    } 
  ]
},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];
```

my problem is in this redirectTo, I lost here the queryParams if they exists.

for example urls that dont work are:

http://mypage.com?lang=de
http://mypage.com/invalidRoute?lang=de

How can I include queryParms in this "redirectTo"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, if someone has interest:

```
  {
    path: '',
    children: [],
    canActivate: [RedirectorGuard],
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },

export class RedirectorGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(
  private router: Router
) {}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
 const queryParams =  route.queryParams.lang ? {
   lang: route.queryParams.lang
 } : {};

  return this.router.navigate(['/main'],  { queryParams: queryParams })
      .then(() => true);
  }
}
```